# Customer Account Data getInvestmentPositions missing data?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I'm trying to use the results from CustomerAccountData API; getInvestmentPositions, with the API call to getAccountTransactions.

Based on the API alone, getInvestmentPositions seems to have enough information such as SecurityInfo but that part never seems to return with the results.  Am I missing an additional call or parameter that I can get the Security Info?  Is there anything I can do to get the getInvestmentPosition service to return more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call 'updateInstitutionLogin' API with refresh flag set to true(PFB ref link). This will trigger an explicit refresh request to the FI. If this call gets successful then please verify if you are getting all the info by calling 'getInvestmentPositions' API.

Update Institution Login

```
URL: https:// financialdatafeed.platform.intuit.com/v1/logins/<loginId>?refresh=true
Method: PUT
Body:
<InstitutionLogin xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/platform/fdatafeed/institutionlogin/v1">
</InstitutionLogin>
```

Ref Link -https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0020_api_documentation/0075_updateinstitutionlogin

Please let us know if it works.

If you still don't get the SecurityInfo in the response of getInvestmentPositions call then please raise a support ticket with  the following details.

1. The response from getInvestmentPositions that shows the account
2. The financial institution ID
3. The account ID
4. The userid(customer) which you are using in the SAML assertion.
5. SAML Identity provider id which you got while setting up AggCat integration

   **The root problem is a bug that is being fixed in the July release.**

   **UPDATE** Issue fix date(most probably) - July'13 29th

   **UPDATE(6thAug) - This issue is fixed now.** Please check and confirm the same from your end.

Comment: I followed your instructions and it did not work.  Quite disappointed.  Looks like I have to create a support ticket.

Comment: Appreciate the update on the bug...if you could, please update this answer when it's fixed then I can accept the answer.

Comment: @critium - July 29th is the release date

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. Can you please mark this qts as answered.
Thanks

Comment: Well, I dont know if I spoke too soon, but now its happening again, but on a different bank.  In fact, it looks like its gotten worse.

Answer (score 2):

The change recommended here does not help. After an explicit refresh and testing multiple accounts with Schwab and Morgan Stanley, the API does not return CUSIP or the stock ticker. This is a deal breaker for anyone who wants to use the Intuit API for personal finance until the issue is resolved. Yodlee does this without an issue.

For e.g. the return is the following for a position:

```
<InvestmentPositions xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/platform/fdatafeed/invposition/v1"     xmlns:ns2="http://schema.intuit.com/platform/fdatafeed/securityinfo/v1">
  <position>
    <investmentPositionId>xxxxxxx</investmentPositionId>
    <costBasis>100000</costBasis>
    <unitPrice>1327.62</unitPrice>
    <marketValue>136397.02</marketValue>
    <units>102.738</units>
    <reinvestmentCapGains>false</reinvestmentCapGains>
    <reinvestmentDividend>false</reinvestmentDividend>
  </position>
```

...